# PostgreSQL format timestamp in h:mm am/pm

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, timestamp

Want to get timestamp/text in format "h:mm a"( from moment js)

For example `SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12:MI am')`

This will give `08:13 am` this result, but I need `8:13 am`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [the fill mode modifier (`FM`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html), whose function is to *suppress leading zeroes and padding blank*:

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'FMHH12:MI am')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=39ff52103cf8ea77c0591c9dad639af0)**:

```
| to_char |
| :------ |
| 8:26 am |
```

Comment: that would remove zero from minutes, but you can try two modifiers?

Comment: This removes leading zeros from hours only, not minutes. If you want to remove the leading zeros from minutes, then you want `'FMHH12:FMMI am'`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `TRIM` here:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH12:MI am'));
```

### Demo

Comment: Good answer, so there is no way to do it with to_char or to_timestamp functions ?

Comment: @Grigor I was thinking of what else I could say in my answer.  It isn't really the job of `TO_CHAR` to handle this.  In fact, just using a single `H12` is not even recognized as a format mask for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "FM"\"FX" format model modifiers to suppress blank and zeroes, both Oracle and PSQL support that, but I never tried that in PSQL

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'FMHH12:MI am')
```

Comment: Why use FXMI instead of MI ?

Comment: FX is "exact match", while FM "ignore blank and zeroes". I advise to experiment. One modifier applies until another used so it to ensure that `:08` will not be `:8`

Comment: I have read about FX/FM in postgres documentation, but do I need to add FX in this case or only to be ensure?

Comment: it looks like it's unncessary there `SELECT TO_CHAR(to_timestamp('20:03', 'HH24:MI'), 'FMHH12:MI am');` same as `SELECT TO_CHAR(to_timestamp('20:03', 'HH24:MI'), 'FMHH12:FXMI am');` `FX` is mostly used for input